# total sum of a row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which gives me the transactions for a user, and the output is a table with the information. There is this row named `basket_value` which contains some numbers, and I need to get the sum of those numbers. Could you please help me?

```
$query3 = 'SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name,users.phone,
           retailer.date, SUM(retailer.basket_value), 
           retailer.time,retailer.location,retailer.type_of_payment
           FROM users ,retailer 
           WHERE users.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
           AND users.user_id=retailer.user_id GROUP BY users.user_id';

$result3 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
    echo "Total ". $row['user_id']. " = $". $row['SUM(basket_value)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: If you do the sum of a column in the table retailer, showing a value's column of this table won't be significant (for example retailer.date doesn't make sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that also your query have some problem and suppose that you have an `id` to retrieve users, I would do in that way

```
$query3 = 'SELECT users.user_id,users.first_name,users.last_name,
                  users.phone, retailer.date, 
                  SUM(retailer.basket_value) as total_sum,
                  retailer.time,retailer.location,retailer.type_of_payment
           FROM users ,retailer WHERE users.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
           AND users.user_id=retailer.user_id
           GROUP BY users.user_id,users.first_name,users.last_name,
                    users.phone, retailer.date,retailer.time,retailer.location,
                    retailer.type_of_payment '

$result = $mysqli->query($query3);
```

Now if you want the sum for each user:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        echo "Player: ".$row['user_id']." total: ".$row['total_sum'];
    }
```

If you want the **WHOLE GLOBAL** sum, you have to way:

- Modify your query in that way:

  ```
  SELECT SUM(retailer.basket_value) as total_sum                 
  FROM retailer
  ```
- Sum into `while` loop like: `$total += $row['total_sum'];`

Comment: Thank you, could you please see my updated question? I'm going to see your answer now i'm trying it!

Comment: Hey, i just tried it, and it is OK, but as you've said i would need the whole sum, could you please modify yuor answer ? i'm not sure what to put here total_sum [...]

Comment: @blerta : i've updated .. this is the WHOLE sum and didn't take into account user_id

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know why, but it won't work like this... , it gives a wrong number!

Comment: @blerta maybe you have a sementichal error... Please try to understand what my sql do and think about it

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `GROUP BY` on your query. You most likely want to add `GROUP BY users.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can omit all other columns in the select list and only have the sum() aggregate run on the set to avoid the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
$query3 = 'SELECT SUM(retailer.basket_value) as total_sum
FROM users ,retailer WHERE users.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
AND users.user_id=retailer.user_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.phone, SUM(r.basket_value) as total_sum
FROM users u
JOIN retailers r
  ON u.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE u.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
GROUP BY u.user_id
```